# Libcurl Issue - "initializer element is not constant"

Tags: c, gcc, libcurl

I'm getting my feet wet with the C `curl.h` library, and am facing a compilation problem with the first example. Based on the [example given here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html), I'm attempting to compile this code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

With this `gcc` command:

```
gcc curltest.c -lcurl
```

And am getting this error:

```
curltest.c:3:14: error: initializer element is not constant
 CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
              ^
curltest.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘if’
 if(curl) {
 ^
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you write:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
```

makes me believe you have all this code on the global level (so not inside a function). On the global level you cannot initialize a variable with a function call and you cannot have execuable statements such as `if`. You need to call the function inside a function for example:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURL *curl;

int main(void)
{
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        //...
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!